# Counting Characters In String Past Certain Character (JS)

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to create a certain calculator, but for it to work I need a way to split a string into two.

Say I have the string `'5+5==10*2'`. I need a way to split the `'5+5'` into one variable/string and `'10*2'` into another.

Is this even possible? What would be the simplest or best way of achieving this in JavaScript?

Comment: `let [left, right] = '5+5==10*2'.split('==')`

Comment: You want to split the string, so how about using `split`?

Comment: Heard of `String.split()`?

Comment: Of course it's possible! What was your own attempt? Would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: string.split("==") => return an array["5+5","10*2"]

Answer (score 0):

Use `split('==')` to get the splited value in array. Then use those values based on your context.

```js
var str = "5+5==10*2";
var res = str.split('==');
console.log(res);
//or print individual value
res.forEach(item=>console.log(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to parse operations represented as string. You can categorize them in 2 parts:

- Comparison
- Mathematical

You can split string with comparison operators into list of expressions. These will be string with operands and operators.

You can further split this string to get individual parts to get data that you can perform calculations on.

Following is a sample:

```js
function getExpressionList(str) {
  var seperateRegex = /==|===|\!=|\!==/;
  return str.split(seperateRegex);
}

function getOperandsWithOP(str) {
  const operatorRegex = /\+|-|\/|\*|^|%/
  const decimalRegex = /\d+/;
  const expressionList = getExpressionList(str);
  return expressionList.map((expression) => {
    const operands = expression.split(operatorRegex);
    const operators = expression.split(decimalRegex).filter(x => !!x);
    return { operands, operators }
  })
}

var str = "5+5==10*2";
console.log(getOperandsWithOP(str))
```

Comment: **Note:** This is not a full fledged calculator. This is just a sample and will not handle many areas. So if you think, something is incorrect/ misleading, please comment along with your vote